# Does QtUiTools.QUiLoader() require QFile as input for some reason?

Tags: python, pyside

I have:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtUiTools
```

---

What is the difference between:

```
ui_file = QtCore.QFile('my_ui.ui')
ui_file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
my_ui = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load(ui_file)
ui_file.close()
```

and:

```
self.ui = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load('my_ui.ui')
```

?

I'm asking because the latter seems a lot simpler, and it seems to work just as well as the first chunk of code. I googled up the first chunk of code and by mistake didn't implement it right, but the .ui file loaded just fine anyways. This made me a little confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the Documentation of `QUILoader::load`, it takes as the first argument a **[QIODevice](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html)** which is basically an interface class that can handle any block of Data such as QFile, QBuffer.

In the  [quiloader.cpp](https://gitlab.com/pteam/korvins-qtbase/blob/38745b341c5c4d49fdb0e87f79f2714f105f63fe/src/uitools/quiloader.cpp) you can see that it tries to open the device and read it's content. Basically your first solution wouldn't need to open the file.

```
QWidget *QUiLoader::load(QIODevice *device, QWidget *parentWidget)
{
Q_D(QUiLoader);
if (!device->isOpen())
    device->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly|QIODevice::Text);
return d->builder.load(device, parentWidget);
}
```

[sourcecode](https://gitlab.com/pteam/korvins-qtbase/blob/38745b341c5c4d49fdb0e87f79f2714f105f63fe/src/uitools/quiloader.cpp)

Comment: Thanks for that link to the quiloader.cpp. That's very useful.